# Preprocessor Definitions VS Local Variables, Speed Difference

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, c-preprocessor

I just compiled the following **C** code to test out the gcc optimizer (using the -O3 flag), expecting that both functions would end up generating the same set of assembly instructions:

```
int test1(int a, int b)
{
#define x (a*a*a+b)
#define y (a*b*a+3*b)
        return x*x+x*y+y;
#undef x
#undef y
}

int test2(int a, int b)
{
        int x = a*a*a+b;
        int y = a*b*a+3*b;
        return x*x+x*y+y;
}
```

But I was surprised to find that they generated slightly different assembly, and that the execution time for test1 (the code using the preprocessor instead of local variables) was a bit faster.

I've heard people say that the compiler can optimize better than humans can, and that you should tell it exactly what you want it to do; man I guess they weren't kidding.  I thought the compiler was supposed to kind of guess at the programmer's intended use of local variables and replace their use if necessary... is that a false assumption?

When writing code for performance, are you better off using preprocessor definitions for the sake of readability rather than local variables?  I know it looks ugly as hell, but apparently it actually makes a difference, unless I'm missing something.

Here's the assembly I got, using "gcc test.c -O3 -S".  My gcc version is 4.8.2; it looks like the assembly output is the same for most versions of gcc, but not on 4.7 or 4.8 versions for some reason

```
test1
        movl    %edi, %eax
        movl    %edi, %edx
        leal    (%rsi,%rsi,2), %ecx
        imull   %edi, %eax
        imull   %esi, %edx
        imull   %edi, %eax
        imull   %edi, %edx
        addl    %esi, %eax
        addl    %ecx, %edx
        leal    (%rax,%rdx), %ecx
        imull   %ecx, %eax
        addl    %edx, %eax
        ret

test2
        movl    %edi, %eax
        leal    (%rsi,%rsi,2), %edx
        imull   %edi, %eax
        imull   %edi, %eax
        leal    (%rax,%rsi), %ecx
        movl    %edi, %eax
        imull   %esi, %eax
        imull   %edi, %eax
        addl    %eax, %edx
        leal    (%rcx,%rdx), %eax
        imull   %ecx, %eax
        addl    %edx, %eax
        ret
```

Comment: How did you measure the performance? As you say, test1 being faster is surprising, so surprising that it casts doubt on the benchmark.

Comment: I assume that if he did look up at the assembly he can tell. I'm surprised that he didn't get the same assembly in the end though.

Comment: benchmarking is a difficult problem. :)

Comment: @delnan I put the two functions in a .c file, compiled it using -O3, then put each function into a for loop that runs 10 million times and timed the execution in main.c, compiling main.c and the other c file with -O0.  The difference in speed isn't much, maybe like a factor of 1 or 2 percent, but it's consistent, and the generated assembly is different, which is what really surprises me.

Answer (score 4):

Trying your code at [godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) I get identical assembly for both functions with GCC, even with -O setting. Only by omitting -O flag I get different results. And this really is expected because the code is trivial to optimize.

Here is generated assembly using gcc 4.4.7 with -O flag. As you can see they are identical.

```
test1(int, int):
    movl    %edi, %eax
    imull   %edi, %eax
    imull   %eax, %edi
    addl    $3, %eax
    imull   %esi, %eax
    addl    %esi, %edi
    leal    (%rax,%rdi), %edx
    imull   %edi, %edx
    leal    (%rdx,%rax), %eax
    ret
test2(int, int):
    movl    %edi, %eax
    imull   %edi, %eax
    imull   %eax, %edi
    addl    $3, %eax
    imull   %esi, %eax
    addl    %esi, %edi
    leal    (%rax,%rdi), %edx
    imull   %edi, %edx
    leal    (%rdx,%rax), %eax
    ret
```

Comment: That's interesting, I'll edit my question and put my assembly in there, I got something different

Comment: @DudeMan2000: what version of GCC are you using?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: GCC version 4.8.2

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Just tried it on GodBolt and found that I got different assembly for GCC versions 4.7 - 4.8.  On every other version I tried it on, I got the same assemby for both functions like you did

Comment: @DudeMan2000 Since GCC is under constant development I guess there can be subtle differences in the resulting assembly even for basic code like this, but the point is that you should be able to trust the compiler to optimize your code and not have to resort to the preprocessor.

Comment: @DudeMan2000: I didn't do anything except ask about the version (specifically, I didn't post the answer). But I'm not shocked that there can be minor differences in the generated code - optimization is a dark and complex art.

Comment: @VilleKrumlinde: So generally the compiler is written to scrap temporary variables when it recognizes them, and this case is kind of a fluke?  Whew, good to know, I'd much rather use local variables than preprocessor definitions!

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Woops, didn't realize you were two different people, hehe, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

## The answer is twofold:

1. Your statement about identical results is a misconception
2. I cannot reproduce your results "`test1` faster than `test2`".

### Preprocessor misconception

The results should not be identical. The **pre**processor acts on (transforms) the source *before* it is actually compiled by the compiler with whatever options.

You can inspect the result of the preprocessor by running `gcc -E main.c` for example, assuming you are using a GNU compiler and your sources above are stored in a file `main.c`. The relevant parts become:

```
int test1(int a, int b)
{
  return (a*a*a+b)*(a*a*a+b)+(a*a*a+b)*(a*b*a+3*b)+(a*b*a+3*b);
}

int test2(int a, int b)
{
  int x = a*a*a+b;
  int y = a*b*a+3*b;
  return x*x+x*y+y;
}
```

Obviously, the first version uses roughly two times more mathematical operations than the second one. Then the compiler and its optimiser come into play …

(NB: Ideally you could analyse the number of CPU cycles generated by the assembler code. Use e.g. `gcc -S main.c` and look at `main.s`; you probably know that. Version 2 should "win" in that case.)

### Runtime testing and optimising

In order to compare our results, you should post your test code. When testing you need to average out short term fluctuations and time granularity limits of your CPU. Hence you are likely to run in loops over the same code.

```
int i=100000000;
while (--i>0) {
    int r;
    r = test1(3, 4);
    }
```

Without optimiser, `test1` runs clearly about 20% slower than `test2`.

However, the optimiser will analyse also the calling code and can optimise away the multiple call with identical arguments or calls with unused variables (`r` in this case).

Therefore you must fool the compiler to effectively make the calls, alike

```
int r = 0;
while (--i>0) {
    r += test1(3, i);
    }
```

When I tried that, I get identical runtimes with a percent level precision. I.e. sometimes `time1` is faster, sometimes `time2` is faster, when I repeat the comparison several times.

You should look into the optimiser documentation to understand which optimising options you need to outsmart in your tests.

And I confirm what @Ville Krumlinde states: I get identical code for the assembly output, even with `-O` level optimisation (gcc 4.4.7 on my desktop). The code only contains 9 operations in assembler, which makes me believe that the optimiser "knows" enough about algebraic optimisation to simplify your formulas.

So you may just be taken by a fake optimiser effect of your test frame after all.

Comment: Note that one of the most basic techniques an optimizer use is "common subexpression elimination" which means that code such as `x=(y*y)+(y*y)+(y*y)` will be transformed into the equivalent of `temp=y*y; x=temp+temp+temp`.

Comment: Yes, it is, @Ville Krumlinde. But then it is also advisable to **give the optimiser optimal hints** about common sub-expressions, alike
`(a*a*a+b)*(a*a*a+b)+(a*a*a+b)*(a*a*b+3*b)+(a*a*b+3*b)` (order changed in the `y` expression). With gcc 4.4.7 that version yields 9 assembler instructions instead of the 12 cited in the question. 
This goes very far, and the question is, if we interpret the question as "How do I optimise formula code?" or "How can preprocessed arithmetic yield different assembler code?" (or "How do I benchmark optimised code?").

Comment: I suppose you changed the order so that `a*a` can be detected as a subexpression and evaluated only once? I can see that could help sometimes, although some of the compilers at godbolt generates the same nr of lines with that version of the code so they seem to be smart enough to detect it anyway.